# what does 'is loaded ' mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[**Source**](http://www.ielts-mentor.com/reading-sample/academic-reading/26-ielts-academic-reading-sample-1-population-viability-analysis)

It is therefore, a scientific fact that increasing the area that **is loaded** in any region will increase the probability that forest-dependent animals will become extinct.

Comment: It's difficult to tell for sure from this excerpt what "loaded" means. However, more context is likely to be very helpful, since it appears to be a term used in the source for a particular meaning.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Unfortunately, the term is not used or explained elsewhere; from the context, it likely refers to population density.

Comment: The subject of the context is *logging* that contributes to extinction of animal populations. It looks like "loaded" is a typo. Substitute "logged" in that sentence and it makes sense.

Comment: @Robusto +1 good thinking. Quite a bizarre typo, though; the letters aren't contiguous on any keyboard. Maybe this is an OCR fail?

Comment: The usual bizarre spellchecking.

Comment: The original seems to be a mock test in this book: https://archive.org/stream/french123/IELTS1#page/n93/mode/2up. Before reading the whole passage (Part A, B, and C), *the area that is loaded* sounded like a typo to me as well. But after seeing the text in part A, I think it's sensible to read *the area that is loaded* as "the area that is loaded with logging", i.e., the area in which  a lot of logging is taking place.

Comment: Except @DamkerngT. "loaded with logging" does not seem particularly idiomatic or formal enough in the given context. I'm not sold on the typo theory either, but mostly because that would mean yet another usage of the verb *to log* in such a short space--a problem the text is probably not concerned with.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about a typo

Answer (score 2):

I think there was a typo.

This is from the original article:

"It is therefore a scientific fact that increasing the area that is logged in any region
will increase the probability that forest-dependent fauna and flora will become extinct."

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hugh-Possingham/publication/321766950_The_role_of_population_viability_analysis_in_forest_management/links/5c68ce3f299bf1e3a5ad40fc/The-role-of-population-viability-analysis-in-forest-management.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In your excerpt

> ...increasing the area that **is loaded** in any region...

the use of ***is loaded*** is a bit confusing.

Usually, when something is "loaded" it means "more is added" or there is an "increased density".  However, the implied meaning from the rest of the text is that cutting down forests will adversely impact animal population viability.

It is possible that "loaded" might be a term for timber logging or it might be a typographic error which was meant to read

> ...increasing the area that **is logged** in any region...

since the rest of the sentence goes to to talk about

> forest-dependent animals